# VS2013: Clicking Compile does nothing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, solution

**See Image for Reference** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujjkt.png

When I click on Complie button(Iniciar in Spanish) the solution gives no errors, everything seems to be ok but the Solution won't start running... BTW this happends almost all the time, not always but atleast 80% of the time, after 9999999 Clicks it starts normally... So I don't know what can be the problem

Comment: Are you sure it's not running?  I can't see all of your code, but the part I do see doesn't contain anything that would generate output.  The program looks like it just does a bunch of math and exits.  Can you post the complete code?

Comment: it's not a problem with the code, the code works perfect, the programs is running and doing what he have to since 7 months ago, but VS2013 is giving that problem since few days ago, the code keeps working everything is ok but VS.

Comment: What should the program be doing when you run it?  Are you sure that you have your program specified as the "Startup Project" in your solution?

Comment: Once again, the programs works perfectly, we are using it in the company since months ago... Everyday I publish new updates for the programs, but SINCE I changed from VS2008 to VS2013, this is happening, it's is VS2013, everything else is OK

Comment: Did you try deleting the .suo file of the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

1. Right click your project and select "Properties"
2. On the "Debug" tab, un-check "Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process".
3. Save project and re-compile.
4. Try and run program

Comment: I'll be testing, as I said it happends likely the 80% so if today it works perfectly I'll will love you for the eternity xD